# Sigsegv when recompiled for arm architecture

Tags: c++, network-programming, arm, poco

I am trying to figure out where I made a mistake in my c++ **poco** code. While  running it on Ubuntu 14, the program runs correctly but when recompiled for the ***arm*** via ***gnueabi***, it just crashes with sigsegv:

This is report from the stack trace (where it falls):

```
socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_IP) = 3
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(8888), sin_addr=inet_addr("192.168.2.101")}, 16) = 0
--- SIGSEGV {si_signo=SIGSEGV, si_code=SEGV_MAPERR, si_addr=0x6502a8c4} ---
+++ killed by SIGSEGV +++
```

And this is code where it falls ( it should connect to the tcp server ):

```
this->address = SocketAddress(this->host, (uint16_t)this->port);
this->socket = StreamSocket(this->address); // !HERE
```

Note that I am catching any exceptions (like econnrefused) and it dies correctly when it can't connect. When it connect's to the server side, it just falls.

When trying to start valgrind, it aborts with error. No idea what shadow memory range means

```
==4929== Shadow memory range interleaves with an existing memory mapping. ASan cannot proceed correctly. ABORTING.
```

http://pastebin.com/Ky4RynQc here is full log

Thank you

Comment: What is the type of address?  Have you checked that `SocketAddress()` is returning a valid address

Comment: It correctly connects to the server, but instead of keeping connection, it fails. So I guess the address is good, WIll check it once more tho.

Comment: Compile the code with -fsanitize=address and run it under valgrind (both on the ARM and the Ubuntu PC). Most likely it's a bug in your code that happens to remain untriggered on the PC. Use-after-free, perhaps, but that is a very wild guess.

Comment: Well, it can't be use after free. There are the only two lines of my method that will run. And both are constructed and used as in example.

Comment: It could be a structure alignment issue. Do you know if `&this->socket` is on a properly aligned address (multiple of 4 if its a 32bit value)?

Comment: @DavidLaPorte It should be ok unless there is error on side of poco.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why, this compiled badly on ubuntu, but when compiled on fedora (same script, same build settings, same gnu), it's working.

Thank you guys for your comments.